# How to control the position of an IK bone using another object

Tags: rigging, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I have a character who needs to open a cupboard. The simplest way to do that seems to be to add a ChildOf constraint to his hand controller, link it to an Empty which is parented to the cupboard and positioned at the same place as the doorknob, and then animate the door's rotation..... except that when I do this, the *whole* rig moves. (It's quite funny, but not what I want.) How do I have the empty affect *only* the position of the hand controller?

[image: Hand controller]

[image: rotate the door and.... whoops]

Answer (score 1):

Doh. I was using an object constraint (which was causing the whole object - ie, the rig - to move) rather than a (second) bone constraint. Which I needed because it's, you know, a bone.

As you were...

Comment: Well, glad you found out by yourself!  Don't forget to key down your bone's transforms before and after keying down the ChildOF constraint influence, it might save you from some headaches down the line.